# SVG Animation Query

Tags: svg

I am brand new to all this, I've been fiddling with SVG stuff for about 2 hours but can't figure out this last thing I want my animation to do.

In short, I have animated an ECG over 6 seconds and the line moves left to right as you see on the hospital monitors on TV. That's all good. What happens next though is the back of the line flows off the screen like a tail following the head - which is fine, but there is this almighty long pause where nothing happens. I have set the animation to 6 seconds and I think, roughly, 3 seconds is the ECG drawing itself left to right and then the last 3 seconds is the tail of the ECG disappearing left to right.

What I would like is for the wave to take 6 seconds to form from start to finish on the wave without such a long pause. And then, is possible, as the wave starts to disappear left to right have a new "head" of the wave start maybe half a second later. So there is a bit of gap between the very end of the first wave and the head of the "second" wave. Sort of like a snake chasing its tail.

Does any of this make sense?
I can send my work so far to anyone via pm and it'll all make sense then.

```css
   html, body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    }

    #pacemaker_01{
    fill:none; 
    stroke:rgb(60,70,255); 
    stroke-width:1.5; 
    stroke-dasharray:4400; 
    stroke-dashoffset:4400;
    animation-name: signal; 
    animation-duration: 6.0s; 
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;}

    @keyframes signal{
    from{opacity:1.0; stroke-dashoffset:4400;}
    to{opacity:1.0; stroke-dashoffset:-4400;}
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I don't think anybody is able to help you withou seeing your code.. Please add it to the question as a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The code is really long but here is the CSS which is much shorter:

Comment: Have you correctly computed the length of your path? The numbers in `strike-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` must match the result of `document.querySelector('#pacemaker_01').getTotalLength()`.